# Using Google Analytics with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics

I'm running a small website/blog running on a node.js server and I'm trying to implement Google Analytics to track views.

I'm using the `universal-analytics` npm module to do this.

I initialise like this:

```
const ua = require('universal-analytics')
const visitor = ua('UA-XXXXX')
```

When a page is requested I run this:

```
visitor.pageview("/<pagename>").send();
```

So far, all I see in my GA dashboard are current active users and it updates quite quickly.  However I would also like to be able to view something such as a request count for each page in total over a time period. That is, I would like it to register a user visit and keep it for me to view later. Is this already being done through `pageview`, or do I need to add something?

Comment: Why dont you just add the analytics js to the head/bottom of your page and let it do it's job? You are not supposed to control analytics and it's irrelevant which framework you are using.

Comment: @Brunis right, how can I tell that it is working? Does it take time for the data to show up on the GA dashboard?

Comment: @Brunis I have done that and removed the calls to `pageview` on the server's end. Now, will I be able to see total page requests or something like so?